# I lost the RAID control drive position

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I have a HP Proliant DL360 with RAID controller.

I had some trouble in the power supply so I removed the 6*250 drives without positioning the drives

After fixing the problem power supply I need to replace the 6 drives but I forget the position of every drive.

How do I reinstall the drives correctly?

Comment: What RAID level was being used?  Was there one large array or??  We need more information about the original configuration.  It may be time to reconfigure the system and restore from backup.

Comment: Depends on the controller but AFAIK with smart array controllers you can move around drives to other ID positions on the same array controller without losing your data

Answer (score 2):

That was sloppy... but you can place the drives in the server, and they *should* be able to recognize the position change.

Watch the server POST process and look for the Smart Array controller message #1724

```
1724-Drive Array - Physical Drive Position Change(s) Detected
```

The message is usually followed with:

```
Logical drive configuration has automatically been updated.
```

No action is needed if you see these messages.

This will tell you that the server recognized the disks' locations changed, but is still able to reassemble the array.

Let the server boot and take more care next time this happens.